# delete with Zend_Rest_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to delete a resource using ZF1 rest client

```
$this->restClient = new Zend_Rest_Client('https://myurl.com');
$response = $this->restClient->delete('/service/'.$this->uuid.'.json?api_key='.$this->apikey);
```

but I get an error:

```
Path "/service/v-2149d050-c64b-0131-33b0-1231390c0c78.json?api_key=a-9a136a00-b340-0131-2662-1231390c0c78" is not a valid HTTP path
```

the web service documentation simply says to use

```
DELETE  https://myurl.com/service/YOUR_UUID.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

any idea on how to use this class?

thanks

Comment: "`?`" is a reserved character in a HTTP URI, if you want to use it inside the path of an URI, you need to percent encode it. In your code you have *not* encoded it.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE  https://myurl.com/service/YOUR_UUID.json?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

That is *not* the path only, but a full URI. It breaks down to:

- Path: `service/YOUR_UUID.json`
- Query-Info: `api_key=YOUR_API_KEY`

For Zend rest client, you need to call one function per each parameter, and a parameter can not be named as a standard HTTP verb:

```
$client = new Zend_Rest_Client('https://exeample.com');
$client->api_key(YOUR_API_KEY);

$response = $client->restClient->delete('/service/'.$this->uuid.'.json);
```

For more information please see [the *Request Arguments* section in the vendor documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.rest.client.html#zend.rest.client.args) on how to pass arguments with your request.

Comment: I tried this way but I get this:
Error: simplexml_load_string(): ^

Comment: @user3174311: Congratulations, you've solved to not get the *"Path XXX is not a valid HTTP path"* error any longer. That was exactly what you asked about, didn't you?

Comment: sure, now I have a different issue.
thanks for your help so far

Comment: btw, this way works the same (except the simplexml error)
    
    $client = new Zend_Rest_Client('https://exeample.com/service/'.$this->uuid.'.json');
    $client->api_key(YOUR_API_KEY)->delete();

Comment: Yes, there are similar ways to do the same with Zend_Rest_Client. See as well the other answer I linked in my first comment under my question. And `simplexml_load_string` gives error if the XML is invalid. You need to look there for errors.